# Create a symbolic link for sublime text in Mac OS X

Tags: terminal, symlink, sublimetext

I have the newest Mac OS 10.12.3. With the new rootless system Apple has implemented, I can't create a symbolic link using `ln` under `/usr/bin`. My goal is so that I can use `subl` in terminal. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The default directory for third-party executables in macOS is /usr/local/bin. Since this directory already is in the PATH you don't have to modify anything except *sudo linking* the executable to this dir.

If the directory doesn't exist, create it with `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`. If you plan to install [brew](http://brew.sh/) later, it's recommended to change the owner of the bin folder to your user.

Comment: `/bin` does not exist under `/usr/local/`

Comment: @B.Li Then create it with `sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin`

Comment: I don't think that automatically creates the link though. Terminal still doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: @B.Li, Saying "_Terminal still doesn't recognize the command._" without also providing the exact command you tried and the exact error message, leaves us without any information to diagnose your issue!

Answer (score -4):

Basically you symlink it. See this answer on github gist https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to create a symlink per se, as using `ln` was already mentioned, but how to deal with SIP while creating a symlink at `/usr/bin`. klanomath's answer already covers making the symlink at `/usr/local/bin` as suggested in the link you posted.